# Mongoid in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am using the Mongoid gem according to this https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/getting-started-rails/
But now i want to make a usermodel with few attributes 
How do i update these attributes in rails controller

```
puts"saving data"

Mongo::Logger.logger.level = :: Logger:: FATAL

client - Mongo::Client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'mydb')

doc ={:_id=>1,:token=> oauth_token, token_secret-> oauth_token_secret} 

client[:UserTable].insert_one doc

client.close 

puts"saved data"
```

The above code directly works with mongodb I want to do this same job via model

Comment: The guide you referenced has a sample application with the relevant code, e.g. https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-demo/blob/master/rails/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create the class for mongoid

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  store_in collection: 'UserTable'

  field :token, type: String
  field :token_auth, type: String
end
```

and later you can use in your controller sentences like:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])

user.update_attributes(update_params)
```